# Modeling growth curves with different starting sizes (NLME in R)

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme, growth-model

I am trying to model fish egg growth over time given a starting egg size in R. I have repeated-measures data from individuals with grouping variable "Zafra.1". I do not know when the eggs started growing, all I know is what the egg size was for an individual at the time of the first measurement. A plot of the data is below.
[image]

This would be similar to modeling length over age, which could be done relatively easily with nlme, except that age is not known. Conceptually, I would like to incorporate some sort of "horizontal offset" so I can use all my data to develop a growth model, even though each individual may have a different starting egg size. This concept is illustrated below:

[image]

I don't think this can be accounted for by allowing each individual to have a different intercept. Perhaps the starting egg size could be added as a term in the model. One option for model I would like to use is below, where "Diametro" is the egg size at time of measurement, "t" is time since the first measurement, and "L0" and "K" are parameters of the exponential curve. This version does not yet include any effect for the different starting diameters, and does not yet include the appropriate random effects structure. A linear model might also work. Ideas?

```
>tail(diam_df)
Zafra.1     Tag Diametro     t diam_0
  <chr>     <int>    <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
1 2013guba 230245     2.30     0   2.30
2 2013guba 230245     2.40    30   2.30
3 2013guba 230248     2.30     0   2.30
4 2013guba 230248     2.40    30   2.30
5 2013guba 230248     2.65   169   2.30
6 2013gU   230415     2.23     0   2.23


EXP=function(x,L0,K) {
y=L0*exp(K*x)
y
}    
EXP.nlme=nlme(D~EXP(t,L0,K))
```

I would like to incorporate random effects for the grouping variable Zafra.1 and at the individual level. How should I set this up in R?

Answer (score 3):

You could have a look at the [SITAR model](https://academic.oup.com/ije/article/39/6/1558/738247) and the associated [**sitar**](https://cran.r-project.org/package=sitar) R package. This models allows for the shifts you are describing.

Comment: Why would someone use SITAR instead of using an NLME directly?

Comment: @usεr11852 AFAICS the sitar package is a wrapper around nlme making it easier to fit this specific model.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your thought +1. That was my general understanding too but I hoped there was something else. (I do not upvote the package itself. If someone needs this functionality, I believe it is far better to invest the time and learn some NLME.)